# Unexpected paint behavior

Tags: netlogo, paint

I want to use a paint command but think have a file problem, not a code problem. This is the code:

```
to color-white
 if mouse-down?
   [ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
       [ set pcolor white]]
end
```

It simply paints in real time when the left mouse button is pushed and pointer passes over the screen. The code works if its written in a new Netlogo session. But if it's used in this file:

[paint-white.nlogo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu6nnql3a8vyk43/paint%20white.nlogo?dl=0)

paint won't appear in real time. Please help.

Comment: I don't think your file loaded. Could you show all of your code? What do you mean it's not painting in real-time? I think your issue is that your color-white function needs to be continuously run. You could run continuously this command in a button in the UI.

Comment: Problem solved: changed view updates from "on ticks" to "continuous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: changed view updates from "on ticks" to "continuous".

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding a call to `display` in your code whenever you want the display to update.  That's how the models in the NetLogo Models Library do it.

"continuous" view updates is a somewhat reasonable alternative, but it involves giving up all control of when view updates occur.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your suggestion, please?

Comment: see also the doc at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#view-updates which goes into this stuff fairly thoroughly

Comment: What is unclear is what you mean by saying "adding a call to display"

Comment: literally insert `display` in your code in places where you want the view updated. see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#display